# How does a Servant client handle received cookies?

Tags: authentication, haskell, cookies, servant

I want to use a Servant client to first call a login endpoint to obtain a session cookie and then  make a request against an endpoint that requires cookie authentication.

The API is (simlified)

```hs
import qualified Servant                       as SV
import qualified Servant.Auth.Server           as AS
import qualified Servant.Client                as SC

-- Authentication and X-CSRF cookies
type CookieHeader = ( SV.Headers '[SV.Header "Set-Cookie" AS.SetCookie
                                  , SV.Header "Set-Cookie" AS.SetCookie]
                      SV.NoContent )

type LoginEndpoint = "login" :> SV.ReqBody '[SV.JSON] Login :> SV.Verb 'SV.POST 204 '[SV.JSON] CookieHeader
type ProtectedEndpoint = "protected" :> SV.Get '[SV.JSON]
-- The overall API
type Api = LoginEndpoint :<|> (AS.Auth '[AS.Cookie, AS.JWT] User :> ProtectedEndpoint)

apiProxy :: Proxy Api
apiProxy = Proxy
```

I define the client as follows:

```hs
loginClient :: Api.Login -> SC.ClientM Api.CookieHeader
protectedClient :: AC.Token -> SC.ClientM Text :<|> SC.ClientM SV.NoContent
loginClient :<|> protectedClient = SC.client Api.apiProxy
```

How does the client handle the authentication cookie? I can think of two ways. When executing a request in the `ClientM` monad, like

```hs
do
  result <- SC.runClientM (loginClient (Login "user" "password")) clientEnv
  [..]
```

where `Login` is the login request body and `clientEnv` of type [`Servant.Client.ClientEnv`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/servant-client-0.18.2/docs/Servant-Client.html#t:ClientEnv), the cookie could part of the `result`, it could be updated in the `cookieJar` TVar inside `clientEnv`, or both. I would assume the TVar to be updated, so that a subsequent request with the same `clientEnv` would send the received cookies along. However, my attempt to read the TVar and inspect its contents using [`Network.HTTP.Client.destroyCookieJar`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.5.13/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#v:destroyCookieJar) revealed an empty array. Is this intended? I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Thus, to make an authenticated call, I would need to extract the cookie from the header in the `result` (how?), update the TVar, create a new `clientEnv` that references this TVar, and make the authenticated call using this new environment. Is this indeed the suggested procedure? I'm asking because I suppose the use case is so standard that there should be a more streamlined solution. Is there? Am I missing something?

Comment: I would expect that the cookie would be re-sent automatically in all requests in the same "`ClientM` monadic block", once it has been set (and assuming cookieJar is not `Nothing`). "my attempt to read the TVar and inspect its contents [...] revealed an empty array" How did you get hold of the TVar? Did you make the cookie-setting call first, without "exiting" the `ClientM` monad?

Comment: It indeed is, but I needed to initialize the TVar first, as described in my answer below. This was my first time dealing with TVars, so it wasn't immediately obvious - in hindisight, it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some experimentation, I figured out that the Servant client indeed does maintain cookies in the `cookieJar` that is part of the `clientEnv`. To be more precise, `clientEnv` contains the field `cookieJar`, which is of type `Maybe (TVar CookieJar)`. It is the TVar the client updates according to the `Set-Cookie` instructions of subsequent requests. It is up to the developer to create and initialize that TVar before making the first request; otherwise, the Servant client will discard cookies between requests.

In addition, it is possible to retrieve cookies in the same way as the request body. To this end, the cookies to be retrieved must be defined as part of the API type, like in the example of my original question:

```hs
type LoginEndpoint = "login" :> SV.ReqBody '[SV.JSON] Login :> SV.Verb 'SV.POST 204 '[SV.JSON] CookieHeader
```

Disassembling the returned was a little tricky at first, because I needed to figure out the final type that results from Servant's type-level machinery. Ultimately, I did the following:

```hs
SV.Headers resp h <- tryRequest clientEnv (loginClient (Api.Login "user" "pwd"))
let headers = SV.getHeaders h
```

where `tryRequest` is a helper to execute `runClientM` and extract the `Right` part. The pattern match `resp` contains the return value (here `NoContent`), while `h` is is an `HList` of the different headers. It can be converted into a regular list of `Network.HTTP.Types.Header` using Servant's `getHeaders` function.

It would then be possible to change or generate new headers and submit them with a new request by adding a new header to the `cookieJar` TVar (see the [cookie-manipulating functions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-client-0.6.4.1/docs/Network-HTTP-Client.html#g:15) in Network.HTTP.Client).